# How to store an image in MySQL using MFC ODBC?

Tags: mysql, mfc, odbc

I'm getting the error message

> error:Conversion is not supported

How to store an image in MySQL using MFC ODBC?

This is my code so far:

```
Cperson person;
person.Open();
person.MoveLast();
person.AddNew();    

CFile   fileImage;
CFileStatus fileStatus;

fileImage.Open(_T("hihi.jpg"), CFile::modeRead);
fileImage.GetStatus(fileStatus);

person.m_Image.m_dwDataLength = fileStatus.m_size;

HGLOBAL hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, fileStatus.m_size);
person.m_Image.m_hData = GlobalLock(hGlobal);

fileImage.Read(person.m_Image.m_hData, fileStatus.m_size);

person.SetFieldDirty(&person.m_Image);
person.SetFieldNull(&person.m_Image, FALSE);
person.Update();

GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
fileImage.Close();
person.Close();
//m_Image is CLongBinary
```

What can I do?
Error in line 'person.Update();'

Comment: In which line are you getting error?

Comment: Use debug mode and step through your code line by line to work out where it fails.

Comment: Does this help at all? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-text-image-columns/managing-text-and-image-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Error in line 'person.Update();'

Answer (score 0):

Try ReadHuge instead of Raad, for more than 64k ReadHuge can be used,

`fileImage.ReadHuge(person.m_Image.m_hData, fileStatus.m_size);`

Comment: I'm getting the error 'ReadHuge' is not a member of 'CFile'.
I'm using Visual Studio 2015